# how to get source code of ASPX file from published website?

Tags: asp.net

I am a software developer. I lost my changes from my local machine.
can i get the source code from published website. If there is any solution please do reply.
thank you

Comment: If you have access to the filesystem of the machine where it is published, you should be able to get back the ASPX files and either the source code files or a compiled DLL. Do you have access to that?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to "decompile" the dll for you're project, so yes it is possible but you'll lose all comments and a lot of formatting.

https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+decompile+dll

First hit, free decompiler:

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx